# Extension, Content Script, 'document_start', Service Workers

Tags: google-chrome-extension, service-worker

I'm looking at this site:

https://www.ukclimbing.com/

And trying to inject from my extension a basic Content Script, at document_start, that simply logs to the console on hearing the DOMContentLoaded event. Nothing happens. I've looked at lots of sites and it's usually not a problem.

Manifest:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "exclude_globs": ["*chrome-extension*", "*google*"],
      "js": [ "scripts/page-event-listener.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    },
],
```

Page Event Listener:

```
function SendRuntimeMessage(pageStatus) { chrome.runtime.sendMessage({pageStatus: pageStatus}, function() {} ); }
function SendBeforeUnloadMessage() { SendRuntimeMessage("complete"); document.removeEventListener('readystatechange', pageSniffer, false); }

var pageSniffer = function(evt){

  var width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
  var height = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;
  var screenSize = [width, height];

  if (evt.target.readyState === "loading") { SendRuntimeMessage("loading"); }

  else if (evt.target.readyState === "interactive") {

      chrome.runtime.sendMessage( { pageStatus: "interactive", screenSize: JSON.stringify(screenSize) }, function() {} );

      //setTimeout so we have a hook in cases where the page never hits the complete event, 5 secs to hit it
      setTimeout(function(){

          if (evt.target.readyState === "interactive") { // this stops the timer from firing even when we've reached the 5 seconds, if we've hit the complete event

                SendRuntimeMessage("complete");
                document.removeEventListener('readystatechange', pageSniffer, false);
                window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", SendBeforeUnloadMessage);
          }

      }, 5000);


  }

  else if (evt.target.readyState === "complete") {

        SendRuntimeMessage("complete");
        window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", SendBeforeUnloadMessage);

  }
};

document.addEventListener('readystatechange', pageSniffer, false);
//add an event listener in case the page is unloaded before the timeout or the complete event is hit
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", SendBeforeUnloadMessage);
```

I've looked at the Sources for the site and my script does not appear on the Content Scripts list. I also noticed that the site is reporting a service worker error.

My general question is this: is there anything about Service Workers that should interfere with the operation of script injection into the sandbox? Has anyone else noticed this about Service Workers? Is this a Chrome bug or am I missing something?

Tom

Comment: Please, show your code and a manifest file

Comment: Extensions I have are successfully injecting their content script on that site so the issue you're having is caused by something in your code, but you haven't posted it.

Comment: Added the code. Thanks.

Comment: The code seems okay. Maybe when you're visiting that site it has `google` in its URL, for example `site.com/path?utm_source=google.com`. Service workers per se don't have anything to do with content script injection.

Comment: The code has been tested on hundreds of other sites so I knew it was OK. Are the other extensions you tested injecting their scripts at 'document_start'?

Comment: Yes they do. Like I said, service workers aren't related to content scripts. You may be hitting some obscure bug. Try reproducing in a new clean user profile, also in another version like Chrome canary 62 etc.

Comment: OK thanks for the attention.